# Is this smooth linear ramp function already a thing?

Tags: functions, machine-learning

In machine learning (particularly with regards to Neural Nets), there's a bunch of "ramp" functions that're used. For example, the ReLU is $0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $x$ for $x>0$.

I was trying to find a nice smooth ramp that was $\sim x$ as $x\to\infty$ and $\sim\frac{1}{-x}$ as $x\to-\infty$. And I came up with

$$
\text{SmoothRamp}(x)=\begin{cases}
    \ x+1 &   x\geq 0,\\
    \frac{1}{1-x} & x<0.
\end{cases}
$$

This ramp also has the nice properties of being differentiable, having $f(-x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$, and being easily computable.

Anyways, my question is: is this smooth ramp already a thing with a common name? Or is it something that I made up?

Comment: In the image that I found in here, https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitions-behind-different-activation-functions-in-deep-learning-a2b1c8d044a, it doesn't seem to be in use, and in a springer article "Quantitative Estimates for Neural Network
Operators Implied by the Asymptotic
Behaviour of the Sigmoidal Activation
Functions," the activation functions considered are $O(|x|^{-\alpha})$ for $\alpha > 1$ as $x \to -\infty$. I'm not an expert but it would appear what you made is new, but I'm not sure if people do/can do analysis on the convergence of a NN with this operator?